# Compare properties from multiple children JSON

Tags: javascript, json

If I have a JSON object like below, how can I pull out all the startdate fields to compare them, so I could, for example, get the minimum start date?

```
{  
   a:{  
      b1:{  
         c1:{  
            startdate:'2017-01-01',
            enddate:'2017-01-02'
         },
         c2:{  
            startdate:'2016-01-01',
            enddate:'2017-01-02'
         }
      },
      b2:{  
         c3:{  
            startdate:'2015-01-01',
            enddate:'2017-01-02'
         },
         c4:{  
            startdate:'2014-01-01',
            enddate:'2017-01-02'
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: In what language?

Comment: Javascript, mainly

Comment: Actually, this is not a valid JSON. JSON requires all keys to be in double quots, like `"enddate":"2017-01-02"`, not `enddate:'2017-01-02'`. `JSON.parse` won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**Like YakovL pointed out:** *The following won't work for you because your json is invalid.*

---

You can't loop through your json because it has no arrays in it. It has just many different attributes.

You can get the data like this:

```
var json = JSON.parse(YourJson);

var startdatec1 = json.a.b1.c1.startdate;
```

You can so the same for all other dates and then compare them. But better change the json like it would make sense. For example make it look like:

```
   [ 
     {
     "startdate":"2017-01-01",
     "enddate":"2017-01-02"
     }
     ,   
     {
     "startdate":"2016-01-01",
     "enddate":"2017-01-02"
     }
     , 
     {
     "startdate":"2015-01-01",
     "enddate":"2017-01-02"
     }
     , 
     {
     "startdate":"2014-01-01",
     "enddate":"2017-01-02"
     }
   ]
```

Then you could to a loop like this:

var json = JSON.parse(YourJson);

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var startDate = json[i].startDate;
    // compare startDates and save the lowest
}
```